# Vuejs - Unbound breakpoint Some of your breakpoints could not be set in VSCODE

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuetify.js

I'm trying to debug vuejs with vscode, I've tried a lot of tutorials/answers and could not make it work.

So I decided to ask a question here, maybe nowadays there's a right way to make it work.

I've created a project that it's identical with the one I want to debug, so I can post prints here.

The project structure is:

[image: Project Structure]

Here is the unbound breakpoint:

[image: Unbound breakpoint]

## Sources Tab in chrome looks like:

[image: Chrome Sources Tab]

## More detailed chrome sources tab:

[image: Chrome Detailed Sources Tab]

## vue.config.js:

```js
/**
 * @type {import('@vue/cli-service').ProjectOptions}
 */
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: "source-map"
  },
  transpileDependencies: true
}
```

## launch.json:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "vuejs: chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
              "**/src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*",
            },
            "preLaunchTask": "vuejs: start"
          }
    ]
}
```

## tasks.json:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "label": "vuejs: start",
        "type": "npm",
        "script": "serve",
        "isBackground": true,
        "problemMatcher": [{
            "base": "$tsc-watch",
            "background": {
                "activeOnStart": true,
                "beginsPattern": "Starting development server",
                "endsPattern": "Compiled successfully"
            }
        }],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

## package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE**

@A.D asked if I've tried to use  keyword

```
debugger;
```

Here is the results:
Ps:  I don't want to start writing debugger in my code...

[image: Debugger Keyword]

But with that i could see that the debugger file is pointing to:

```
C:\Users\vinic\Desktop\test\test\js\webpack:\test\src\components\HelloWorld.vue
```

But the component src is actualy located in

```
C:\Users\vinic\Desktop\test\test\src\components\HelloWorld.vue
```

Why my breakpoints are not bounding?

Comment: Tried using the debugger keyword?

Comment: I've just updated the post with the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appearently there are some problems with the webpack of vue versions above 2.6.11

[Git hub Thread](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/11023#issuecomment-789137369)

[Reddit Thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/v6bipb/why_is_vue_2614_file_no_longer_available_in/)

After some discussions with @Tonielton Mota i noticed that, if I fully remove the property name from package.json and package-lock.json it works.

Here are the files that are working:

## launch.json

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "vuejs: chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
              "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
            },
            "preLaunchTask": "vuejs: start"
          }
    ]
}
```

## package.json

```json
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change webRoot param and leave as in the documentation, you need to include **src** after **${workspaceFolder}**.

```
{
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "vuejs: chrome",
  "url": "http://localhost:8080",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
  "breakOnLoad": true,
  "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
    "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
After some research, i found this [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/12689).
There is a change in this version that you used.
They changed the compiler and this affected the way to debugger.

You can use the **"2.6.11"** works in this version.

*Note: This change affected later versions.*

Comment: still not working

Comment: You need to restart your application, stop the server and run again.

Comment: I did it. But I've just noticed that if i remove the property 'name' of the package.json it works

Comment: It's not make sense for me, I just created a project, followed the doc and It's works for me.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/debugging-in-vscode.html

Comment: I've tried exactly this documentation. If you take a look at the pictures I've posted, the source maps are under test/src not webpack://src

Comment: this             "sourceMapPathOverrides": {  "**/src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*",   }   or  "sourceMapPathOverrides": {  "test/src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*",   } should resolve it, but it doesn't

Comment: Ok, but your sourceMapPathOverrides is different too... 
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
      }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247067/discussion-between-vinicius-andrade-and-tonielton-mota).